# Trying to understand geom_bar aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am confused about how `ggplot` is handling an aesthetic in some data I'm working with.

I've got some data showing the start `ptype` and end `atype` type for transit passengers in a number of cities. Additionally, the sample is weighted. You can download the data straight from Dropbox with the `repmis` package.

```
MyData <- repmis::source_data("https://www.dropbox.com/s/62v84hn9wmwpo6b/MyData.csv")
```

About 75 percent of trips in this data go from a home to a work, but the proportion is different in every city. I want to visualize this (unweighted) table by city:

```
table(MyData$ptype, MyData$atype)/nrow(MyData)

        Other School  Work
  Home  0.055  0.130 0.750
  Other 0.040  0.005 0.000
  Work  0.010  0.010 0.000
```

This code does it, but `y = ..count..` is the last thing I tried (of course, but I tried lots else first).

```
# problematic
ggplot(MyData, aes(x = ptype, fill = city, weight = weight)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", aes(y = ..count.., group = city), 
           color = "black") + facet_grid(atype ~ .)
```

[image: Using ..count..]

The more natural thing to me would have been `y = ..density..`, but this is obviously wrong, because each category sums to 1 *within each facet* rather than *across the plot*

```
# problematic
ggplot(MyData, aes(x = ptype, fill = city, weight = weight)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", aes(y = ..density.., group = city), 
           color = "black") + facet_grid(atype ~ .)
```

[image: Using ..density..]

In fact, `..count..` seems so counterintuitive, I wonder if it's wrong. Can someone explain this to me?

Or point me to a better way to visualize this problem?

Comment: You do not appear to have raw values. Why not just use `stat = "identity"`?

Comment: I have weighted values, but the rows represent individuals, not calculated statistics. So `identity` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my `weight` variable sums to one within each group, because I calculated it that way. So the `..count..` aesthetic with the weighted variable will itself sum to one. I guess I need to figure out how to make this chart work with unweighted data, but this works for now.